# How to make a dynamic start destination in the Android Jetpack Navigation

Tags: android, navigation, android-jetpack

I am building an SMS app, using the [Navigation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-implementing) pack from [Android Jetpack](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/) to navigate between screens.

When users open my app for the first time, they land on a permissions screen where they need to grand default app permissions and some regular permissions before they can move into the main screen.

I also need to show the permissions screen when the user changes their default SMS app and then reopen my app.

I saw the [Conditional Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-conditional) section in Android Navigations docs. It suggests placing this logic in the main screen fragment `onViewCreated` method. But I am afraid that it will impact the startup time of my app.

Is there a more efficient way to implement this? Ideally, I would like to handle this logic in the activity.

Answer (score 26):

Don't set the navigation graph in the XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/navigationHostFragmentMain"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:defaultNavHost="true" />
```

In your `Activity` you can set the start destination programmatically and then set the navigation graph.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    setNavigationGraph()
}

private fun setNavigationGraph() {
    val navHostFragment =
        supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.navigationHostFragmentMain) as NavHostFragment
    val navController = navHostFragment.navController

    val navGraph = navController.navInflater.inflate(R.navigation.navigation_graph)
    navGraph.startDestination =
        if (viewModel.isLoggedIn) {
            R.id.homeFragment
        } else {
            R.id.loginFragment
        }

    navController.graph = navGraph
}
```

Comment: Beware, that explicitly setting the navGraph every time in `onCreate` will lead to a fresh "navigation instance", e.g. after an orientation change you are back at your (possibly adapted) start destination which is probably not what you want. As a solution you can only set the graph the first time, so when `savedInstanceState == null`

Comment: Have you tested that? If configuration changes cause the activity to be recreated then the view for the `Activity` will be inflated again in which case we will have to set the graph again since we have not done so in the `XML` file ?? Maybe it would make sense to reuse the navigation graph instead of inflating it every time. I am not sure. I'll test if you have not already.

Comment: Ah sorry, I missed that you don't set the graph in the layout xml anymore. My described problem only happens if you additionally have the graph set up in the xml. If you only set it in `onCreate` you're good even on a configuration change.

Comment: it leads to crash with error Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: no start destination defined via app:startDestination

Comment: Remove "app:navGraph" from fragment container view of activity layout

Comment: Does not work for me always goes to home page not login

Comment: is it correct do it this way? I'm building an activity that has different games as in fragments, and want to set the destinations at runtime based on user's choice of game.

Answer (score 7):

You can set startDestination of the graph programatically like this

```
val graph = findNavController(R.id.YOUR_CONTAINER_ID).graph
graph.startDestination = R.id.ID_OF_THE_FRAGMENT_FOR_START_DESTINATION
findNavController(R.id.YOUR_CONTAINER_ID).setGraph(graph)
```

This can be executed in your Activity's onCreate() method